# Calling instance method without specifying instance name

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

I have Two Classes - `Chatroom` and `User`.

`Chatroom` has a function to remove a specified user from the `Chatroom`s array list.

```
public void removeUser(User u)
{
    if(userlist.contains(u)){
        userlist.remove(u);
    }
}
```

And in the class `User` there is a method called `leaveRoom`. This method forwards the `User` parameter to the `removeUser` method of the instance of `Chatroom`.

```
public void leaveRoom(final Chatroom name)
{
    name.removeUser(this);
}
```

However, it requires for the instance name of the `Chatroom` class to be given to the function as parameter. Working with blueJ I have to put type this into the window when calling the method from the instance of `User`.

Now I have been wondering if there is a way to call the right method in the right instance of `Chatroom` WITHOUT having to specify the instance name as a parameter?

EDIT:

A user can only be in one chatroom at a time. The goal is to `leaveRoom()` the current chatroom without having to specify it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. The way things are defined you must pass a `Chatroom` to the `leaveRoom` method. Your other option is to pass a `User` to the `removeUser` method of the `Chatroom`.

Comment: Well the question would be how to pass the current Chatroom the User is in to the leaveRoom method IF that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `User` instance has only one `Chatroom` they can be in, you could keep a reference to that `Chatroom` in the `User` class, and then you wouldn't have to supply any parameter to `leaveRoom`.

However, if a `User` can be simultaneously in multiple `Chatroom`s, the `leaveRoom` method must be told which room to leave, so the parameter would be necessary.

If the `User` can only be in one room at a time, the code can look like this:

```
public class User {

...
    private ChatRoom currentRoom;
...
    public void leaveRoom()
    {  
        if (currentRoom != null) {
            currentRoom.removeUser(this);
            currentRoom = null;
        }
    }
....
}
```

Comment: A user can only be in one chatroom at a time. The goal is to leaveRoom() the current chatroom without having to specify it.

Comment: I have tried it. (Chatroom is not written ChatRoom btw) It doesn't work. The user is still in the chatroom after I use the leaveRoom() function.

Comment: @RomanRutkowski Do you initialize `currentRoom` when the `User` joins the room?

Comment: Never mind. I specified joinRoom() to save the room that is being joined as the currentRoom. Works like a charm now. Thanks.